# Modern troops transported from Germany to a fantasy realm after nuclear holocaust

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to find a book series I read in the last few years (1-3 years ago). I think it's a recent publication (maybe last 10 years but can't be sure).

The first story involved:

- Nuclear holocaust causing a transport from Germany to a fantasy realm
- Modern weapons slowly stop working in the fantasy world
- Schizophrenics become wizards
- Faith in our world religions makes you immune to magic (healing and damage)

I believe it was a mix of NATO troops, primarily US and German, supposed to be a force stationed in Germany to fight Russia (this I am a little fuzzy on).

Comment: Sounds like the set-up for *Tanks vs. Trolls*!

Comment: One other question I just realized I should have asked: Was this book printed as a paperback? (Or hardback?) Or just something you downloaded to read as a Kindle e-book, for instance? (I'm asking because these days there seem to be tons of SF/Fantasy novels available on Amazon which never had a printed edition.)

Comment: E-book is most likely, tried going back through my kindle account but couldn't find it so assuming it was a download, used to travel a lot so read on my phone to make it easier

Comment: Hmm...  Some vague memories.  Did they have an armoured personnel carrier?  Some white phosphorus munitions?

Comment: Quite possible, it was a large group that came across (division or corp level strength I think), they used a nuke at one point to destroy an enemy army.

Comment: @davidw You might be thinking of *The Doomfarers of Coramonde*, where a US APC gets transported from Viet Nam to a fantasy world.

Comment: @LAK Just now I came back and saw DavidW asking about an APC with white phosphorus, and the same novel instantly popped into my head! Then I kept reading the other new comments and saw you'd already suggested *Doomfarers* might be what he had in mind (although apparently it is not what Sully is remembering).

Comment: @LAK Right, that's the one.  I forgot it was Vietnam, and according to the OP's comment it needs to be a lot larger force.

Comment: Doomfarers did come up in my searches but wasn't the one I was looking for, the refuge series is the right one, but I will try and read that next. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a total guess, but could it be [the *Refuge* series by Doug Dandridge](https://www.goodreads.com/series/183209-refuge)?

The summary of the first book in the series, [*The Arrival*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18895712-refuge), is:

> In the year 2025 a nuclear war breaks out in Central Europe, the Russians trying to secure their old empire. The dimensional gates open to another world, a world of magic, where our dreams of fantasy are real. The evil Emperor of the Ellala sees the millions of transplanted humans as soul energy to forward his scheme for immortality. He orders his armies to capture the newcomers, to place them in concentration camps where they can be harvested. But the Germans, French, Polish and other peoples or Earth have other ideas. With the help of their American allies and the modern weapons of war they will fight back against the magic of the evil elves, while gathering their own allies in the fight for survival. For they are seen by the native peoples as the fulfillment of an ancient prophecy. And they have brought immortals with them to this world. men and women of great power on Earth, who become true demigods on the new world. So it is tank against mage, attack helicopter against dragon, and nuclear warheads against impregnable fortress, as the humans must use their technology while they still have it, and gain a foothold on a world beyond their understanding.

So it kind of matches your description, and the timing is right since it was published in 2012. Try as I might, I cannot find a copy of the book to check the details. If I do manage to find one I will update this answer.

Comment: That looks like it and have read some of their other works so makes sense,going to mark it as the answer and see if I can find it again, thank you so much for the help

Comment: Can confirm this is the series, thanks again for all the help, was going insane trying to remember it